# Update properties between 2 entity instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Lets say that i have 2 instances of the same entity, `a` and `b`

```
a.SomeProp = 2;
b.SomeProp = 1;
```

I would like to update `a` with `b`:s properties:

```
a = b;
context.SaveChanges();
```

(`a` is attached to the context, `b` is not)

However, the values are not updated. I suppose im doing it the wrong way. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
a = b
```

then you set `a` pointing to the same object as `b` (and the original object pointed to is discarded).

You need to assign the properties you want to update, like:

```
a.SomeProp = b.SomeProp
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you create a method on that entity that does the copy, or you create something like a [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Method of copy would be something like:

```
a.CopyFrom(b);
```

where

```
void CopyFrom(Entity b)
{
    a.SomeProp = b.SomeProp;
    a.SomeProp2 = b.SomeProp2;
...
}
```

The [= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) doesn't do what you want.
Also note, you cannot overload the = operator if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you are. You are replacing your instance a with b - so a and b will both not be attached to the context.

You need

```
a.SomeProp = b.SomeProp
```

Answer (score 0):

SaveChanges performs the update between all the data as retrieved from the entity framework and to the adjusted objects in your context. Is there a way to get b from the context as well?  Doing the same thing with an object that is originating from the context this would work for.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but you might try this.

```
dc.Entry(a).State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;
dc.Entry(b).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```